# I cannot push the already hosted app on bitbucket to heroku

Tags: git, heroku, bitbucket

I have my repository on bitbucket. And I want to deploy my app on heroku. I have pushed the repo on heroku too. But when i open my app [appName].herokuapp.com I got this error:

> An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in > a few moments.
>
> If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

Even the result of pushing on heroku shows success. But I am unable to run my app. Also I got this error in console:

> Blocked a frame with origin "http://s3.amazonaws.com" from accessing a frame with origin
>   "http://{appName}.herokuapp.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to look into the logs: `$ heroku logs -n 200`

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#log-history-limits

There I found that I had bad credentials for PostgreSQL.